# MVC Database to list with id reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I'm writing an MVC application and want to query my database with a search parameter and put all of the results into a list. Right now my code to try this looks like:

```
Character character = db.Characters.ToList().Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Which is throwing up a error. Is there a way I can do this? Break it down into two statements for example? I tried

```
Character character = db.Characters.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
character = character.ToList();
```

but that isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

When using the extension method `Find()` you must be sure that in your model you have the attribute [Key] in the property representing your Id (primary key in your table).

And you can try like this:

```
Character character = db.Characters.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

The line above will work but not this one `character= character.ToList();` because you declare character as an object and you can't assign it to a list of object in your case `Character`

If you want it to work, you can do something like this:

```
 var myCharacters =db.Characters.Where(c=>c.someField=="someValue");
 List<Character> myList = myCharacters.ToList();
```

Hope it will help.